# Does smtp.office365.com make regional restrictions on useing as the SMTP_HOST?

Tags: smtp, office365

I am using smtp.office365.com as my SMTP_HOST, With the same creds I can send emails from my VPS in German but it says `response: '535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [TYCPR01CA0182.jpnprd01.prod.outlook.com`  in my japan server.

I found that the mail service is using

`FR3P281CA0144.DEUP281.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM` in my mail service working VPS.
And
`TYCPR01CA0182.jpnprd01.prod.outlook.com` in VPS which shows the Authentication Unsuccessful message.

I double checked the Creds in both server. I want to know If there is any regional block in using outlook main service. If so what should I do in order to fix this?